# How do you organize your file downloads?

Tags: filesystems, file-management

Somewhat of an unconventional question on here, but I'm curious as to how you guys organize your files (and if there are any automated tools you use).

Often times, I just end up keeping everything in my Downloads folder and it gets messy real fast. Are there any Marie Kondo-esque conventions that are a great way to organize?

[image]

Comment: I download to a specific folder I have and as soon as downloaded, I move it to the permanent folder where it belongs. My permanent folders are very highly organized.  This is in the category of a highly opinionated topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Skip the Desktop and dont clutter it

2.In downloads categorize the file types while storing

3.Whenever you put categorize the file while inserting like images zip executable etc

4.Do this process regularly to prevent clutter

5.Use descriptive file names

6.Use search to find files which you think could not sort

7.Refrain using too much folders keep organized

8.Follow and stick the same rule

Comment: Please try not to answer off topic questions ...